# if i have two limits going to negative infinity and a function that is differentiable , does that mean there has to exist a maximum?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, infinity

Suppose that $f(x)$ is differentiable for every $x\in\Bbb R$ and that $$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x) = -\infty$$, then there exist a maximum point $\in\Bbb R$

so i was thinking if i can use Wiestrass theorem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x) = -\infty$, you can find $M>0$ such that $f(x) < f(0)$ for $x \notin [-M;M]$. Then as $f$ in continuous on $[-M,M]$ it reaches a maximum at say $y \in [-M,M]$ which is also a global maximum because $f(x) < f(0) \le f(y)$ for $y \notin [-M,M]$.

Comment: False. Consider $p(x)=-(x+1)^2$ and for all $-1<x<0$ then $f(x)>f(0)$

Comment: You are right. I made a typo between $x \in [-M;M]$  and $x \notin [-M;M]$ in the first line.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net i dont understand why we need f(0) and also how did you decide that f(x) < f(y)

Comment: In fact I used $f(0)$, but you can replace $0$ in the proof by whatever real point $x_0 \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Why you cannot have $f(x)\geq f(0)$ is not evident, or replacing 0 with any real value.

Comment: You can have $f(x)  \ge f(0)$ BUT only for $x \in [-M,M]$. $M$ has been selected for that using the definition of $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x) = -\infty$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Hope you can help to check out if my proof is right, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

First notice that $$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x) = -\infty$$ is equivalent to saying $\forall M<0, \exists x_0>0 $ such that $f(x)<M \ \forall x\geq x_0$ or $x\le -x_0$. by definition.

In the light of this, we can "crop" down the domain of $\mathbb R$ into $I=[-x_0,x_0]$ to look for the maximum, knowing that if there is one, it must be in $I$.

Then, since differentiability on a interval implies continuity, we conclude that $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $I$.

Naturally, a closed, bounded interval with a continuous function $f(x)$ defined on it must have $f$ bounded on $I$. (Boundedness theorem)

Finally, since $f$ is bounded on closed interval $I$, we conclude there is an absolute maximum value on $I$. (Extremum value theorem) Thus, f reaches a maximum value.

QED.

Comment: Looks good, except that you can be more precise by saying that $f$ reaches its maximum rather than is bounded. A function can be bounded without reaching its extrema.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion!